# Is there a Dictionary object for FreePascal?

Tags: generics, dictionary, freepascal

It's incredibly impossible to find things for FreePascal because all searches end up at some sort of Delphi related site.

Is there a built-in Dictionary object?

[This page](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Templates#Generic_classes) references "TDictionary" under the Generic Classes section, but I have no idea what unit it might be in, or if it even exists.

Comment: Unit `fgl` contains generic classes defined [`here`](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Generics#Introduction). An example using `TFPGMap`: [`Class Map or Dictionary, anyone?`](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=18441.0).

Comment: Closest, indeed, is fgl.TFPGMap I think. LU RD: make it a proper answer so that it can be accepted.

Comment: To Google articles prepend "fpc pascal" to your searches

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The unit [`fgl`](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Generics#Introduction) contains the basic generic classes for `freepascal`.

Among those classes, the closest to a `TDictionary` is `TFPGMap`.

An example how to use this class can be found here: [`Class Map or Dictionary, anyone?`](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php?topic=18441.0).

Comment: Forget about `TFPGMap`. It is implemented as **array**, which is just too slow for any purpose. Even using an actual array would be faster. If you are forced to use it, you need to set `sorted` to true, then it uses at least a binary search for reading rather than a linear one.

Comment: @BeniBela so what did you end up using?

Comment: @jj_ First I [benchmarked them all](http://www.benibela.de/fpc-map-benchmark_en.html). Rtl-generics seem to be the best overall, but I do not trust them below fpc 3.1. (complex generics are tricky, even Lazarus crashed when I opened their source) ghashmap.THashMap is an okay fallback. Although I ended up using the hash map from Bero's [Fast Light Regular Expressions library](https://github.com/BeRo1985/flre), because I was already using that library for regexs and it is surprisingly fast

Comment: Thanks! Good source of updated info for someone new to Free Pascal.

Answer (score 7):

You can use very compatible TDictionary from Generics.Collections unit:

- https://github.com/dathox/generics.collections
- http://bugs.freepascal.org/view.php?id=27206

works for FPC trunk rev. 30239 and newer.

**Edit 05.08.2016**

Generics.Collections library has been added to FPC trunk as rtl-generics package in r34229. Latest version of precompiled FPC trunk (with Generics.Collections) for Win32 + Lazarus trunk available at http://newpascal.org . The repository of Generics.Collections ( https://github.com/dathox/generics.collections ) will be still used for maintenance (should be synced often with FPC trunk).